# Why should Next() operation of a singly linked list be protected with a critical section?

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

I'm reading the book *Multithreading Applications in Win32*

The book says `return node->next` will be compiled into separate machine instructions that would not be executed as an atomic operation, so `Next()` should also be protected by the critical section.

My question is, what instructions could it be translated into, to cause a race condition?

```
typedef struct _Node
{
    struct Node *next;
    int data;
} Node;

typedef struct _List
{
    Node *head;
    CRITICAL SECTION critical_sec;
} List;

List *CreateList()
{
    List *pList = malloc(sizeof(List));
    pList->head = NULL;
    InitializeCriticalSection(&pList->critical_sec);
    return pList;
}

void DeleteList(List *pList)
{
    DeleteCriticalSection(&pList->critical_sec);
    free(pList);
}

void AddHead(List *pList, Node *node)
{
    EnterCriticalSection(&pList->critical_sec);
    node->next = pList->head;
    pList->head = node;
    LeaveCriticalSection(&pList->critical_sec);
}

void Insert(List *pList, Node *afterNode, Node *newNode)
{
    EnterCriticalSection(&pList->critical_sec);
    if (afterNode == NULL)
    {
        AddHead(pList, newNode);
    }
    else
    {
        newNode->next = afterNode->next;
        afterNode->next = newNode;
    }
    LeaveCriticalSection(&pList->critical_sec);
}

Node *Next(List *pList, Node *node)
{
    Node* next;
    EnterCriticalSection(&pList->critical_sec);
    next = node->next;
    LeaveCriticalSection(&pList->critical_sec);
    return next;
}
```

**Edit:**

OK, although in this particular case it won't corrupt the singly linked list w/o protecting the `Next()` operation, a shared structure should be protected as a whole or nothing, generally.

Comment: What happens if the node is deleted after `next` is read, but before the code makes use of it?

Comment: This could happen even with the critical section. The node could be removed after `LeaveCriticalSection`, but before `return next`.

Comment: Yup, definitely. :) That's why they say it's a bad idea to implement thread synchronization code in containers -- they don't help you anyway. Just thought I'd point that out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`return node->next` performs two operations; it first loads the `struct` pointed to by `node` into memory, then looks at the `node+offsetof(next)` to find the pointer `next`, load that into a register, and then return to the calling program. The contents of `node` may be manipulated by another thread of execution in the meantime.

Comment: Depending on the contents (which can only be the `next` field in this case) to be modified by another thread or not, `Next` returns either the old next node or the new next node. To me, it's totaly fine. Is there a race condition?

Comment: @Eric: Getting an old node may be catastrophic if the other thread freed the node's data and control structure... [There are ways to make working with stale data meaningful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-copy-update), but the design is subtle.

Comment: You convinced me, sarnold. Although it won't corrupt the link in this particular case w/o protecting the `Next()`, generally a shared structure should be protected as a whole. It should be locked all-or-nothing.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, you absolutely need to protect your "next" with a lock in a multithreaded application.

... HOWEVER ...

1. "Writers" (like add or remove node) *MUST* be mutually exclusive.  Critical section is a good choice.
2. "Readers" (like "next") can run concurrently with each other.

SUGGESTION:

If you can target Windows Vista or higher, consider using an SRW lock instead:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa904937%28VS.85%29.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163405.aspx

Comment: Could you point me to a race condition case if I don't use critical section in `Next`?

Answer (score 1):

While I think the answer by sarnold is correct, I just wanted to point out that the sizeof() call in your malloc() call in CreateList appears to have a bug.  I believe it should be:

```
List *pList = malloc(sizeof(List));
```

The way you had it, you will create enough memory to hold a *pointer* to a List and not the List structure.  (You may also want to cast the return type to (List*) and compare it to NULL before using it..)